# Время жизни access token

Tags: php, javascript, vkontakte-api

На сайте реализую авторизацию через это https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile, все успешно получилось,но access token живет всего 86400 секунд,можно ли как то увеличить это время или какие то  методы,что бы пользователю не пришлось каждый 24 часа проходить авторизацию
Вроде здесь долго держится вход.http://thequestion.ru/

Comment: `scope=offline` - без срока жизни

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, Спасибо!А как Вы считаете,это оптимальный способ иметь вечный токен?Правильно ли это?

Comment: "Если срок использования ключа истек, то необходимо повторно провести все описанные выше шаги, но в этом случае пользователю уже не придется дважды разрешать доступ."


То есть по запросу авторизации вы сразу получите новый токен. Это вроде как нормальная практика. К слову, некоторые сайты дают метод для "продления" токена, здесь же не нужно писать отдельно новый/продление, просто запросил авторизацию если токена нет или он истек.